# Change action color of snackbar from style

Tags: android, android-snackbar, material-components, material-components-android, snackbar

I need the `AppTheme.colorAccent` to be brown but I need my `Snackbar` action color to be blue. How to change action button color of `Snackbar` from style without changing `AppTheme.colorAccent`?

I've try this code but it does not work :

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Design.Snackbar" parent="android:TextAppearance" tools:override="true">
    <item name="colorAccent">#3097ff</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

With the Material Components Library you can do it.

Just add the **`snackbarButtonStyle`** attribute in your theme app.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    <!-- Style to use for action button within a Snackbar in this theme. -->
    <item name="snackbarButtonStyle">@style/snackbar_button</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Then define your custom style:

```
  <style name="snackbar_button" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Snackbar">
      <item name="backgroundTint">@color/secondaryLightColor</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

It requires the version 1.1.0 of the library.

Comment: Had to do something like that with Material3 library v1.8.0 otherwise the action text seems to be somehow hardcoded to pink.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the color in the `colors.xml` and use it in the `snackbar` as follows:

```
val mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.container),"Item added to cart.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
mySnackbar.setAction("view cart", View.OnClickListener {/*action to be triggered*/  })
mySnackbar.setActionTextColor(/*color defined*/)
mySnackbar.show()
```

I implemented this in Kotlin.